# Changing property on one element causes other elements to stop appearing

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, visual-studio-2015, xamarin-studio

I am working the DeveloperWalkthrough example from developer.xamarin.com. Everything works after adding the imageview and the second layout with the two text widgets. When I change the orientation value of the root linear layout, the second linear layout with the two text widgets disappears from the designer

Here is the source code

```
    <xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
            <TextView
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView1" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView2" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Attached are the before and after screenshots of the designer when I change the root LinearLayout orientation to horizontal

Answer (score 0):

Your `ImageView` in the `LinearLayout` has a width of `match_parent`.  This means it's going to fill out the entire screen. Your elements aren't disappearing, they're being pushed off-screen.  They're siting next to the `ImageView`.  Shorten the width and you can see them.

Comment: That did the trick.  Thanks DeeV.  Obviously I have a lot learning to do